# ¿ request.remote_ip desde el modelo?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Cómo puedo obtener la `IP` desde el modelo, cuando le asigno un valor salva solo null.

Ejemplo:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  before_create :asignar_ip

  def asignar_ip
    self.ip_inicial = request.remote_ip
  end

end
```

¿Alguna idea?

**Actualización**

Estoy trabajando con la gema `devise` y por lo mismo no tengo acceso al controlador de `users`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías generar tu propio controlador de registro (que herede del de *Devise*) y definir/modificar la acción `create` de *Devise*, en la cual puedes actualizar ese atributo; por ejemplo:

```
# app/controllers/registrations.rb

class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    super
    resource.update!(ip_inicial: request.remote_ip)
  end
end
```

Lo que estás haciendo es simplemente redefinir la acción `create` para que tenga el comportamiento normal de *Devise* (para eso es `super`) pero antes de terminar la acción, tomar el objeto `resource` (i.e. usuario) generado y agregar el atributo `ip_inicial`.

Ahora solo debes indicar en tu archivo *routes.rb* que *Devise* utilice este nuevo controlador:

```
# config/routes.rb

# ...
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "registrations" }
```

---

**Respuesta anterior**

El objeto `request` únicamente está disponible en el controlador, por lo tanto debes leer su valor ahí y después asignarlo a un atributo del modelo.

Dado que quieres asignar el valor de `ip_inicial` al crear el objeto (i.e. `User`), te recomiendo pasarlo como un parámetro más de tu modelo al momento de crearlo; por ejemplo, asumiendo que tu modelo `User` tuviera los atributos `name`, `email` e `ip_inicial`, harías lo siguiente en el controlador:

```
User.create(name: "Gerry", email: "gerry@test.com", ip_inicial: request.remote_ip)
```

Y en tu modelo `User` ya no haría falta poner *callbacks* o *métodos* adicionales.

Comment: Saludos amigo Gerry, el tema es que estoy trabajando con la gema devise y no tengo acceso al controlador de user como tal, ese es el punto de inflexión

Comment: @rrg1459 He actualizado la respuesta, mírala y dime si te funciona.